# Android Studio spawning multiple java processes! How to minimize its memory usage on a low-ram machine?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

I'm running Android Studio on an underpowered machine, and when I was monitoring Android Studio's memory consumption I noticed multiple "java" processes, some even forking another process as a child and some taking as much as up to 1 GB!

Is this normal behavior or is it the result of a misconfiguration?

And how can I configure this to work with less number of java processes?

Will changing the project's JDK and Gradle to an externally installed (more recent version) help rather than using the ones shipped with Android Studio?

[image: Android Studio and Java Compiler Memory Usage]

Comment: This is almost certainly normal behavior. Using android studio on a low memory machine is probably difficult/not practical.

Comment: What you are likely observing is the gradle import. How much memory do you have?

Comment: View here for configuring a custom JVM: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under?page=5. I don't think it will help much. One thing I would recommend is running a full gradle build outside of the IDE, so that gradle isn't doing as much when you build inside the IDE. There are also other settings you could fiddle with like this one: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limited Java compiler and Gradle to 512mb and updated Gradle to the latest supported version by Android Gradle plugin and that remedied the high memory use to some extent, now only noticing 3 java processes max and each around 512mb.

For anyone curious these are the flags I used:

Android Studio Custom VM options:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

gradle.properties :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Fixed heaps's start and max size to 512mb to avoid recalculation.
Thanks to everybody who answered.

UPDATE 11/25/2020: The issue seems to be noticeable more when Android Studio is set to use an **external Gradle** installation along **external JDK** installation. When Android Studio is set to use the internal JDK and Gradle, both the IDE and the Gradle worker depend on **one** Java process but when they are working externally they spawn their own Java process and cannot intercommunicate.
P.S: I did upgrade to a more powerful machine, and builds are way more faster and smoother.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I am using flutter, can you please just tell me how to apply the settings you mentioned above?

Comment: @MohamedYousof For the VM options: Android Studio -> Help -> Custom VM Options.  And then copy and paste the above inside the window. As for the Gradle options, open the gradle.properties and edit according to the values mentioned above.

Comment: I had memory problems, when I used Android-studio locating in old Ubuntu-version disk from new version Ubuntu-version. I think this leads to situation, where I have Android Studio is set to use an external Gradle installation along external JDK installation. All 16GB memory was used in 10 mins and huge number java-processes were pawned, when I was just changing projects configuration, but did nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

As @PiPRocks said, using Android Studio on an underpowered machine is almost impractical.

For smooth working of Android Studio your machine should have atleast 8GB of RAM and if it has a GPU it adds up but is not necessary.

**Coming to Your Question...**

This is normal behaviour of Android Studio. It keeps the IDE process and Gradle process separate (with the name of 'java'). And if you are running an Emulator, you'll see another process.

Comment: `For smooth working of Android Studio your machine should have atleast 8GB of RAM` you should probably find a source for this :)

Comment: I quote that. I have used Android Studio on an 4GB RAM machine and I know the struggle.

Comment: So, my machine has 24GB and it would repeatedly crash. Do you consider this a normal behavior?